MOSFET keeps dying on totem pole driver
I am designing a 3-phase motor driver for a 300 W hoverboard motor with a Raspberry Pi Pico, which has 3.3 V logic, for driving the MOSFETs I am using a discrete totem pole driver on the n channel MOSFETs, made with 9015 PNPs and 2N2222 NPNs, paired with a level shifter and a inverter for non inverting input, for the p channels I have a single transistor driver.
At the initial tests the n channel MOSFETs only overheated and died, which was normal at 5 V Vgs and low switching frequency (9 kHz at the time), after fixing these issues I raised Vgs to 10 V and frequency to 16 kHz, which made the n channel MOSFETs last much longer, after that I replaced the fake IRF1405 I was using for testing with HN75N09AP, which are the MOSFETs that were on the original driver for the motor, and they died after seconds, furthermore the 4k7 input resistor on the schematic is actually 5 Ω, something I discovered just now after killing all the HN75N09AP I had, now I would like to know what killed them as the totem pole circuitry is fine in on/off tests, and there is really scarce information on them and they didn't even heat up, was it the high frequency? Improper driving? Lack of gate resistor?
Here is the only information I found for the MOSFET specs.
I plan on replacing them with new original IRF3205.


Looks like there's an error- collector of Q6 and Q5 should not be connected, n'est-ce pas?

Q3 is also upside down.

thanks for the advice, fixed the schematic and the circuit is same as schematic

Do you drive the high and low side with one signal(16khz_pwm)? Because one of them should be inverted. These drivers are both noninverting.

(@MichalPodmanický The high-side driver is inverting.) Do you really intend to drive the Q1 with the PWM signal? Using a 1 k pull-up, the driver doesnt provide for fast turn-off.

FYI, D2 and D3 are superfluous; the MOSFET symbols already show two diodes inside, actually.

You are kinda shorting the VS node to ground.
When the driving signal from 16khz_PWM node is HIGH, the Q1 will be on by the Q7 level shifter. With the Q5 and Q6 cascade inverters (i.e. inverting twice) and the post push-pull driver (Q2-Q3) the Q4 will see a positive gate-to-source voltage so it'll be on as well.
The delays coming by the cascade inverters and the push-pull driver is negligible for 16 kHz. Therefore both MOSFETs will be on right at the same time, shorting the supply rail.
If the circuit was supposed to be a part of a H-bridge or a totem pole driver then get rid of one of the pre-inverters because the Q1 and Q4 are not supposed to be turned on or kept on at the same time:

You may need to make some further adjustments to the component values.

R1 doesn't have to be that small. It can be increased to a few tens of kΩ to decrease the dissipation.
R2 can be moved to the collector (between D1's anode and Q7's collector) unless the intention is to form a current source there i.e. R2 brings a local feedback and turns the Q7-R2 network into a current source.


furthermore the 4k7 input resistor on the schematic is actually 5 ohm

If you mean R5 = 5Ω then you may also have killed either Q6 or the Pico's pin as well because the base current could be really high (even with 3V3 driving signal). Keep R5 high, 4k7 is good.
EDIT:
From the OP's comment:

... the pwm was labeled incorrectly, the bottom side is inverted by the code itself

So there are two independent PWM signals, if I understood correctly. In that case, the only possibility that comes to mind is the shoot-through or having overlapped drive signals i.e. if Q1 and Q4 stay on at the same time (e.g. due to unnecessarily slow rise and fall times or insufficient dead time) this will effectively short the VS source and the high current may kill at least one MOSFET. Leave a dead time between the drive signals, for 16 kHz PWM a few hundred nanoseconds could be enough to start with.

thanks for the suggestions, i will definitely try them as i already have a dead pico, the pwm was labeled incorrectly, the bottom side is inverted by the code itself, that is why i have a inverter before the level shifter, to keep the signal the same, is it correct?

@pedrohcs8 the pwm was labeled incorrectly update your question with this information. Also please see my updated answer.

@pedrohcs8 If they are timed exactly (same but inverted) -- or even if there is notable dead time added -- because Q1 isn't driven by an emitter follower, it turns off so very much slower than Q4 that even some microseconds of dead time likely is not enough. The PMOS may also be prone to parasitic turn-on.

I think larger values for R1 will make things worse. The current source idea seams to be intended.

With a P-channel MOSFET high-side, its gate must be low to switch it on.
The low-side N-channel device requires its gate to be low to switch it off.
Consequently, gate potentials must be in phase. By your node-naming, both inputs have the same signal, "16kHz PWM". The upper section inverts once, but the lower section inverts twice, so the gates are 180° out of phase, meaning that both MOSFETs are on at the same time, or off at the same time. You'll probably need to remove one of the inverting stages Q6 or Q5 to fix this.
While I don't want to do much analysis, I will point out some other issues that might need your attention.
Q5 and Q6 are both connected common-emitter, and will enter deep saturation when on. It can take many microseconds to recover from that state, meaning that each inverting stage will introduce a potentially significant delay before transitioning from on to off. Importantly, though, that delay is absent when transitioning from off to on.
These delays can be deliberate and useful, or they can cause instants when both MOSFETs are (at least partially) on, causing shoot-through. You'll need to examine timing very closely to identify potential issues.
By contrast, Q7 has emitter degeneration from R2, which is no doubt a deliberate choice to prevent over-saturation (mitigating the associated on-to-off delay), and to accommodate the zener diode, but the cost is that you have to be very careful what high and low potentials you apply to Q7's base. You can no longer assume that any old high/low digital signals will work correctly, as you could for Q6.
Update: after some calculations, I estimate that a +5V signal at the left end of R3 would probably work, but not +3.3V. If you are signalling with 0V & +3.3V signals, then you should reduce R2 to 220Ω.

(I think the high side should be drriven by a "polarity" signal, not PWM.)

@greybeard I estimate that 0V and 5V input there would be OK, but not a 3.3V signal.

sorry for the misleading labeling it was fixed on the schematic, actually the bottom one is inverted by the code itself, that is why i thought i needed to re-invert after the inverted level shifter, so really what i should do?

@pedrohcs8 you should do whatever is necessary to keep gate potentials changing in phase with each other.

@SimonFitch so yeah, in this stage they kind of do fine, in static testing 0 shorts, i was just wondering about the extremely short life of the mosfets i was using even on 30w

@greybeard True for classic DC motor drive, but in a 3 phase system?

(After some more thought: should work, but even with ideally sinusoidal signal for one third of the time when that phase is highest, not for all of the half-cycle, leaving one twelvth before&after where it would need to switch fast. Probably too much of a hassle for little perceivable gain.)
